# Notice that the wp_enqueue_style is not being called correctly! 

Tags: wp-enqueue-script, wp-enqueue-style

I get this error due to one of the plugins which I rely on.

Notice:  wp_enqueue_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles
should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts,
admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks.

What does this error mean and how do you fix it? 
Mind due that this is not a critical error. It only appears when I put WP into debug mode.

The full plugin-code is below.

It's one heck of a plug in that makes it a breeze to deal with the highly complicated and hierarchical cats. I'm posting it not *just* for the sake of debugging where the bloddy error is but *also* to hope that it helps someone.

```
<?php /*

**************************************************************************

Plugin Name:  Category Collapse
Description:  Makes children categories hidden on the Write screens until an icon is clicked.
Version:      2009.02.12
Author:       Viper007Bond
Author URI:   http://www.viper007bond.com/

**************************************************************************/

class CategoryCollapse {

    // Plugin initialization
    function CategoryCollapse() {
        if ( !is_admin() ) return;

        wp_enqueue_style( 'category-collapse', plugins_url('/category-collapse/category-collapse.css'), array(), '2009.02.12', 'screen' );
        add_action( 'admin_head', array(&$this, 'edit_form_advanced') );
    }


    // Output the Javascript (it's not in an external file due to the dynamic image URLs)
    function edit_form_advanced() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#categorychecklist li").addClass("catcolpadding");
        $("#categorychecklist ul.children").hide().parent("li").removeClass("catcolpadding").addClass("cathaschildren catcollapsed").prepend('<img class="catcoltoggler" src="<?php echo plugins_url('/category-collapse/images/plus.gif'); ?>" alt="+" title="Show Children" />');
        $("#categorychecklist .catcoltoggler").click(function(){
            var parent = $(this).parent("li.cathaschildren");
            if ( parent.hasClass("catcollapsed") ) {
                $(this).attr({ src: "<?php echo plugins_url('/category-collapse/images/minus.gif'); ?>", alt: "-", title: "Hide Children" });
                parent.removeClass("catcollapsed").addClass("catuncollapsed").children("ul.children").slideDown();
            } else {
                $(this).attr({ src: "<?php echo plugins_url('/category-collapse/images/plus.gif'); ?>", alt: "+", title: "Show Children" });
                parent.removeClass("catuncollapsed").addClass("catcollapsed").children("ul.children").slideUp();
            }
        });
        $(".cat-checklist li").addClass("catcolpadding");
        $(".cat-checklist ul.children").hide().parent("li").removeClass("catcolpadding").addClass("cathaschildren catcollapsed").prepend('<img class="catcoltoggler" src="<?php echo plugins_url('/category-collapse/images/plus.gif'); ?>" alt="+" title="Show Children" />');
        $(".cat-checklist .catcoltoggler").click(function(){
            var parent = $(this).parent("li.cathaschildren");
            if ( parent.hasClass("catcollapsed") ) {
                $(this).attr({ src: "<?php echo plugins_url('/category-collapse/images/minus.gif'); ?>", alt: "-", title: "Hide Children" });
                parent.removeClass("catcollapsed").addClass("catuncollapsed").children("ul.children").slideDown();
            } else {
                $(this).attr({ src: "<?php echo plugins_url('/category-collapse/images/plus.gif'); ?>", alt: "+", title: "Show Children" });
                parent.removeClass("catuncollapsed").addClass("catcollapsed").children("ul.children").slideUp();
            }
        });
    });
/* ]]> */
</script>
<?php
    }
}

// Start this plugin once all other plugins are fully loaded
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', create_function( '', 'global $CategoryCollapse; $CategoryCollapse = new CategoryCollapse();' ) );

?>
```

Comment: thanks. Tried it but did not work. the new error is Notice: wp_register_style was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or init hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in ... on line 3587

Comment: Would you mind posting the plugin's link? I cannot find it neither in the repository nor in Viper007Bond page...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The problem is that the [`wp_enqueue_style()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) call is inside of the `category_collapse()` member function of the `CategoryCollapse()` class, and the `CategoryCollapse()` class is being instantiated by a callback hooked into the `plugins_loaded` action hook.

That means that the `wp_enqueue_style()` function is attempting to execute at the [`plugins_loaded` hook, which fires *before* `init`, `wp_enqueue_scripts`, and `admin_enqueue_scripts`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference#Actions_Run_During_a_Typical_Request).

To fix, replace this:

```
wp_enqueue_style( 'category-collapse', plugins_url('/category-collapse/category-collapse.css'), array(), '2009.02.12', 'screen' );
```

...with this:

```
function wpse49339_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'category-collapse', plugins_url('/category-collapse/category-collapse.css'), array(), '2009.02.12', 'screen' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse49339_enqueue_styles' );
```

That way, the `wp_enqueue_style()` call will be hooked into `wp_enqueue_scripts` instead of firing directly at `plugins_loaded`.

Comment: It worked Chip. Thank you. I'm going to paste the working code as an answer below for somebody to simply copy and go.

Answer (score 0):

//here is the working and bugfree code

```
<?php /*

**************************************************************************

Plugin Name:  Category Collapse
Description:  Makes children categories hidden on the Write screens until an icon is clicked.
Version:      2009.02.12
Author:       Viper007Bond
Author URI:   http://www.viper007bond.com/

**************************************************************************/

class CategoryCollapse {

    // Plugin initialization
    function CategoryCollapse() {
        if ( !is_admin() ) return;
        //begin modifitication  
        //per bennet's suggestion on http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/49339/notice-that-the-wp-enqueue-style-is-not-being-called-correctly/49344#49344      
        //the following org code is commented out
        //wp_enqueue_style( 'category-collapse', plugins_url('/category-collapse/category-collapse.css'), array(), '2009.02.12', 'screen' );
        //and replaced with this;
        function wpse49339_enqueue_styles() {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'category-collapse', plugins_url('/category-collapse/category-collapse.css'), array(), '2009.02.12', 'screen' );
        }
        add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse49339_enqueue_styles' );
        //end modification  
        add_action( 'admin_head', array(&$this, 'edit_form_advanced') );
    }


    // Output the Javascript (it's not in an external file due to the dynamic image URLs)
    function edit_form_advanced() { ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        $("#categorychecklist li").addClass("catcolpadding");
        $("#categorychecklist ul.children").hide().parent("li").removeClass("catcolpadding").addClass("cathaschildren catcollapsed").prepend('<img class="catcoltoggler" src="<?php echo plugins_url('/category-collapse/images/plus.gif'); ?>" alt="+" title="Show Children" />');
        $("#categorychecklist .catcoltoggler").click(function(){
            var parent = $(this).parent("li.cathaschildren");
            if ( parent.hasClass("catcollapsed") ) {
                $(this).attr({ src: "<?php echo plugins_url('/category-collapse/images/minus.gif'); ?>", alt: "-", title: "Hide Children" });
                parent.removeClass("catcollapsed").addClass("catuncollapsed").children("ul.children").slideDown();
            } else {
                $(this).attr({ src: "<?php echo plugins_url('/category-collapse/images/plus.gif'); ?>", alt: "+", title: "Show Children" });
                parent.removeClass("catuncollapsed").addClass("catcollapsed").children("ul.children").slideUp();
            }
        });
        $(".cat-checklist li").addClass("catcolpadding");
        $(".cat-checklist ul.children").hide().parent("li").removeClass("catcolpadding").addClass("cathaschildren catcollapsed").prepend('<img class="catcoltoggler" src="<?php echo plugins_url('/category-collapse/images/plus.gif'); ?>" alt="+" title="Show Children" />');
        $(".cat-checklist .catcoltoggler").click(function(){
            var parent = $(this).parent("li.cathaschildren");
            if ( parent.hasClass("catcollapsed") ) {
                $(this).attr({ src: "<?php echo plugins_url('/category-collapse/images/minus.gif'); ?>", alt: "-", title: "Hide Children" });
                parent.removeClass("catcollapsed").addClass("catuncollapsed").children("ul.children").slideDown();
            } else {
                $(this).attr({ src: "<?php echo plugins_url('/category-collapse/images/plus.gif'); ?>", alt: "+", title: "Show Children" });
                parent.removeClass("catuncollapsed").addClass("catcollapsed").children("ul.children").slideUp();
            }
        });
    });
/* ]]> */
</script>
<?php
    }
}

// Start this plugin once all other plugins are fully loaded
add_action( 'plugins_loaded', create_function( '', 'global $CategoryCollapse; $CategoryCollapse = new CategoryCollapse();' ) );

?>
```