# can't access dashboard and showing forbidden page

Tags: hooks, dashboard, wp-register-script

i cant access my dashboard. after i make true the wp-debug it shows the following error.

```
Notice: wp_register_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.) in /var/www/html/enteopinion/wp-includes/functions.php on line 3012
```

what should i do to make the site dashboard to work well? i used a plugin simple error handler.it shows the following errors.

```
Error trapped: USER NOTICE(1024), wp_register_script was called incorrectly. Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the wp_enqueue_scripts, admin_enqueue_scripts, or login_enqueue_scripts hooks. Please see Debugging in WordPress for more information. (This message was added in version 3.3.)
 /var/www/html/enteopinion/wp-includes/functions.php[3012]
 /var/www/html/enteopinion/wp-includes/functions.wp-scripts.php[57]
 /var/www/html/enteopinion/wp-settings.php[197]
 /var/www/html/enteopinion/wp-config.php[90]
 /var/www/html/enteopinion/wp-load.php[29]
 /var/www/html/enteopinion/wp-admin/admin.php[30]
 /var/www/html/enteopinion/wp-admin/plugins.php[10]
```

what to do with these errors? :( please help me

Comment: The notice (not error) that you're seeing isn't likely the cause of your inability to to access the dashboard (but it does need to be fixed). Take a look at your error logs to see if there are any other clues - i.e. actual errors that will point you in the direction.

Comment: and by 'forbidden' to you mean 403 error? Check file permissions and web server configuration.

Comment: yeah.. it shows "you dont have permission to access the file /wp-admin/widgets.php" etc. but when i refresh the site again it displays the actual dashboard. but there is some unusual things in the site due to this notice.i mean by unusual is the live site shows elements in different positions on each page refreshment.

Comment: [Check this out](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/49344/13615)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the short sweet answer.

Somewhere you, a plugin, or your theme are doing something like this:

```
wp_register_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/myscript.js', '', '', true );
```

What should be happening is this:

```
add_action(
  'wp_enqueue_scripts',
  function() {
    wp_register_script( 'myscript', get_template_directory_uri() . '/path/to/myscript.js', '', '', true );
  }
);
```

From the `Notice`:

> Scripts and styles should not be registered or enqueued until the
>   `wp_enqueue_scripts`, `admin_enqueue_scripts`, or `login_enqueue_scripts`
>   hooks

In other words, somewhere scripts are being registered prematurely. By hooking to one of the hooks listed in the `Notice`, or any hook after those run, you ensure that the scripts are registered when they should be and not before.